# Can someone tell me from which url Maven downloads the archetypes when i type mvn archetype:generate?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I seem to be having problem with finding the archetypes for maven in cmd. The list is too long and cmd seems to show only the last entries of the 1420 archetypes. Also on eclipse also displays a few archetypes for a Maven project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Maven looks for the archetypes:

- in the following remote catalog: http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml.
- in the catalog present in your m2 user folder.

This is documented in the [`archetypeCatalog`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeCatalog) attribute of the [`generate`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-archetype-plugin`. The default value for this attribute is `remote,local` where:

- 'local' is the shortcut for 'file://~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml'
- 'remote'  is the shortcut for Maven Central repository, i.e. 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'

Comment: Can you explain the syntax "mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.apache:struts". I tried it but doesn't seem to work. And also how to use the filter "choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): org.apache:struts" that comes after the generation?

Comment: @Birendra There are no archetype with a groupId of `org.apache`. Try with `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.apache.struts` (note the `.` instead of `:`)

Comment: yeah. For example i typed this command "mvn archetype :generate -DgroupId=am.ik.archetype" to get the archetypes of that group which is available for sure. But it still returns me the whole list. Why is that ?

Comment: @Birendra Because you need to use `-Dfilter` and not `-DgroupId`: it should be `-Dfilter=am.ik.archetype`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Maven is telling me "Your filter doesn't seem to match any archetype"

Comment: @Birendra Right, you need to use `-Dfilter=am.ik.archetype:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91318/discussion-between-birendra-and-tunaki).